# Add column to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to add a column to my SQL Server table. Is it possible to do so without losing the data, I already have?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Of course! Just use the [`ALTER TABLE...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) syntax.

Example

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD Foo INT NULL /*Adds a new int column existing rows will be 
                     given a NULL value for the new column*/
```

Or

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD Bar INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0) /*Adds a new int column existing rows will
                                    be given the value zero*/
```

In SQL Server 2008 the first one is a metadata only change. The second will update all rows.

In SQL Server 2012+ Enterprise edition the second one is a [metadata only change too](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/).

Answer (score 20):

Use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columname DATATYPE(size);
```

And here is an example:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD LastName VARCHAR(50);
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

Adding a column using SSMS or `ALTER TABLE .. ADD` will not drop any existing data.

Answer (score 3):

Add new column to Table

```
ALTER TABLE [table]
ADD Column1 Datatype
```

**E.g**

```
ALTER TABLE [test]
ADD ID Int
```

If User wants to make it auto incremented then

```
ALTER TABLE [test]
ADD ID Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Add new column to Table with default value.

```
ALTER TABLE NAME_OF_TABLE
ADD COLUMN_NAME datatype
DEFAULT DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Comment: Your answer would be way better if you added a brief explanation on what's going on here.